# log in user automatically - Swift Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swift5

i have an application that have two viewControllers, the first one is for the login and the second one is a tableViewController and it is the main viewController for the application. Im trying to keep the user login automatically after closing the application and navigate to the main viewController. i tried this code and it is from firebase documentation but when i start the application it shows Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

this is my code for the AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var db: Firestore!
var firebaseToken: String = ""
var window: UIWindow?
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    
    self.registerForFirebaseNotification(application: application)
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    
    

    handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
        if user != nil {
         
            
            let main = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                   let vc = main.instantiateViewController(identifier: "viewController") as! ViewController
                   self.window?.rootViewController = vc
                   window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
            
        } else {
            // ...
        }
    }



    return true
    
}
```

Comment: When you login the first time, you have to save the `credential` into `UserDefaults` and when the app is closed and re-launched you can use that credential to `signInAndRetrieve` data with the saved credential, if data is there take user to Home Screen else to Login Screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            // Logged
            let main = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = main.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = vc
            window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
           
        }else{
            //Not logged

        }
```

Comment: i tried it but after login and relaunch the application it not navigate to the main viewController and showing log in viewController

Comment: Welcome Fetih Tunay, thanks to share your question. Please do not put only the code as text in the question. Add a description of your problem. Please also read [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to understand how to write good questions.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication automatically stores the user credentials to disk when they sign in. When you restart the app, Firebase automatically restores the user's state from those credentials. But this process requires a call to the server (for example, to check if the account has been disabled), which means that by the time your `Auth.auth().currentUser != nil` runs that call probably hasn't yet completed and the current user *is* nil.

The solution is to use an auth state listener as shown in the first code snippet in the documentation on [determining the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

```
Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
    if user != nil {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: So let's remove the `handle` in that case. I updated the code in my answer. On it not working: if you put a breakpoint on `if user != nil {` and run in a debugger, does it hit that breakpoint? If so, what's the value of `user`? Now if you let it run, does it hit the breakpoint again? If so, what's the value of `user` now?

Comment: Hey @sar71. Did you make any more progress on this?