# log in user automatically like Instagram - Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, swift5

I'm using firebase for my application and I'm trying to log in to the user automatically like Instagram and other social media applications. I tried to use UserDefaults, firebase currentUser but it doesn't remember the user after relaunching the application

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var db: Firestore!
    var window: UIWindow?
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()    
        if let _ = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            let homeController = mainViewController()
            self.window?.rootViewController = homeController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        } else {
            let rootController = loginViewController()
            self.window?.rootViewController = rootController
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()  
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: As explained here, you'll need to use an auth state change listener for that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67203024?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase modules are asynchronous and do take time to re-auth the user can take time. This means accessing the currentUser before the auth state has finalized will result in the user appearing to not be loaded.

Instead, you should be listening to the Auth state. You can find the documentation for swift here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start#listen_for_authentication_state